# How does the Perfect Wight prestige class's Improved Legerdemain feature work?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, rogue, prestige-class, sneak-attack, epic-tier

The Perfect Wight prestige class from the *Epic Level Handbook* (page 34) gains the Improved Legerdemain feature at 2nd level.

- Could the perfect wight use this to touch a device that is inside a  force sphere?
- Along the same lines: Can the perfect wight use Improved Legerdemain to make a sneak attack on a target that is inside an *Otiluke's resilient sphere*?
- If the wight decided to use this to make a sneak melee full attack, does Improved Legerdemain apply to all the attacks? (For example: When a rogue-shadow dancer-perfect wight makes 9 attacks in a full round, is he able to use Improved Legerdemain to make all the attacks sneak attacks and at a distance of 30 feet?)

I'm guessing that the answer would not be different if the perfect wight was incorporeal or not. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: The prestige class is also in the SRD [here](http://dndsrd.net/perfectWight.html#perfect-wight).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *Perfect Wight’s Improved Legerdemain* class feature is a [supernatural ability](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#supernaturalAbilities).

"Using a supernatural ability is a standard action unless noted otherwise". Hence you can’t use *Improved Legerdemain* to make one (or more) melee sneak attacks as part of a full attack.

The more difficult part of the question is whether you can use this ability to manipulate things or to touch/attack someone inside *Otiluke's Resilient Sphere*, a *Force Cage* or behind a *Wall of Force*.

Force effects like the above-mentioned allow line of sight but block line of effect because they provide total cover.

The definitions of "Line of Effect" given in the Player's Handbook and the srd either refer to physical attacks or to spells, like on page 176 of thhe PH:

> A line of effect is a straight, unblocked path that indicates what a
> spell can affect. A line of effect is canceled by a solid barrier.
> (...)
> You must have a clear line of effect to any target that you cast a
> spell on or to any space in which you wish to create an effect.

*PH 176 on aiming a spell*

Supernatural Abilities, of course, aren’t spells. So it’s not clear whether they also need Line of Effect to work.

The *Rules Compendium* though extends the definition of Line of Effect by including "abilities".

> Line of effect tells you whether an effect, such as an explosion, can
> reach a particular target. A line of effect is a straight, unblocked
> path that indicates what an **ability**, effect, or spell can affect. A
> solid barrier cancels line of effect.

*RC, 80 (emphasis mine)*

The sidebar on the same page also directly refers to force effects.

> There is also a small set of effects, usually magical, such as wall of
> force, that impair line of effect but not line of sight. These effects
> can generally be described as transparent barriers—they are not a
> barrier to sight, but physical objects and magical energy cannot pass
> through them.

"Magical energy" seems to be a vague term but since Supernatural Abilities are magical they are most likely included here.

So, coming back to your question: no, the *Perfect Wight* can't use this ability to touch a device that is inside a force sphere, neithher can they make a sneak attack on a target that is inside an *Otiluke's Resilient Sphere*.

Comment: Wow, I admire your knowledge Peregrin Took. Thank you very much, this is perfectly celar!

Comment: @Digius Oh thanks, I feel flattered... :)

Comment: Why would you need line of effect when "the perfect wight and his or her weapon do not physically cross the intervening distance." That would seem to be code for *not* needing line of effect.

Comment: @HeyICanChan There need not be a physical movement. The su ability - or the "magical energy" - is simply unable to reach past a barrier that blocks the path. It cannot create an effect there.